# How do UIImageView autoresize according to UIImage's size

Tags: cocoa-touch

How do UIImageView autoresize according to UIImage's size?

imageView.image = image2;

Now, the size of image2 is (Width = 123.0; height = 123.0); and the size of imageView is (Width = 18;height=18);
My problem is, could imageView autoresize to (123.0,123.0) ? I have all type of the property UIViewContentMode, but imageView didn't change its size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can alter imageView.frame=CGRectMake(position.x,position.y,size.x,size.y);

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass `UIImageView` (say, `AutoresizedImageView`) and override `-setImage:` method in it:

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage*)image{
    [super setImage:image];
    self.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
}
```

Haven't tried it myself but I think it should work fine